# Exclude node_modules minification to solve "Failed to minify the code from this file" with unexpected path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, push-diffusion

When I run npm run build (`react-app-rewired build`) I get this compilation error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file: 

./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--6-oneOf-2!./node_modules/diffusion/src/node_modules/util/interface.js:127
```

I am trying to use `config-overrides.js` to inject the *excludes* attribute as
`config.optimization.minimizer[0].options.exclude = /node_modules\/diffusion/;`

but this does not seem to work (neither using only `/node_modules/`)

Any help?

PS. I managed to avoid minification altogether overriding "mode" in the *config* from "production" to "development".

I also noticed that we are using version 5.9.2 of the diffusion library and that upgrading to the latest version the minification issue is gone.

My understanding though is that we need the older version because of a breaking change in version 6. Is there a way to disable minification only for this specific library?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will help you:https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3734

Comment: This solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53700102/regex-to-exclude-npm-library-from-minification