# Regex to exclude npm library from minification

Tags: javascript, regex, webpack, push-diffusion

I have to use a non open source pub/sub library for websockets ([diffusion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diffusion/v/5.9.2)) and have to stick to a specific version because it's what is used on the server side and I have no control about it.

The issue is that in one single util in their code base they use the reserved keyword `interface` and that triggers a minification error that breaks the build:

```
Failed to minify the code from this file: 

    ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib??ref--6-oneOf-2!./node_modules/diffusion/src/node_modules/util/interface.js:127 

    Read more here: bit.ly/CRA-build-minify
```

**Which regex can I use to exclude this dependency from minification?**

`config.optimization.minimizer[0].options.exclude = /node_modules/;` does not ecxlude it from minification.

`config.optimization.minimizer[0].options.exclude = /^.*(node_modules|.js).*$/;` works but it's too broad

---

For more context, this is the code of the dependency that is causing the minification to fail:

**node_modules/diffusion/src/node_modules/util/interface.js**

```
function _implements() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  var impl = args.pop();
  var unsatisfied = [];
  ...

  // The joys of duck type. Quack quack
  args.forEach(function(interface) {          <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
      unsatisfied = unsatisfied.concat(interface(impl));
  });
```

---

This is how the webpack config file looks like before my overrides: (we are not allowed to eject)

```
"optimization": {
    "minimizer": [
      {
        "options": {
          "test": {

          },
          "extractComments": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "cache": true,
          "parallel": true,
          "terserOptions": {
            "output": {
              "ecma": 5,
              "comments": false,
              "ascii_only": true
            },
            "parse": {
              "ecma": 8
            },
            "compress": {
              "ecma": 5,
              "warnings": false,
              "comparisons": false,
              "inline": 2
            },
            "mangle": {
              "safari10": true
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "pluginDescriptor": {
          "name": "OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin"
        },
        "options": {
          "assetProcessors": [
            {
              "phase": "compilation.optimize-chunk-assets",
              "regExp": {

              }
            }
          ],
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185027/discussion-on-question-by-ga-sacchi-regex-to-exclude-npm-library-from-minificati).

Comment: Solution: `/node_modules|chunk\.js/;`

Comment: Won't this exclude the whole `node_modules` folder?

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed as of version 6.0.0

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to fix when not ejecting IMO.

You're probably using old version or react-scripts, just upgrade it to `react-scripts@>=2.0.0`.

Taken from [this section](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/troubleshooting/#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify) of **React Documentation**